# WooCommerce - Change page title when tab is not active

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, tabs, title

I am looking for function for WooCommerce which change meta title text in non-active tab. Anybody know how can I do it? I find this JS code but it does not work in themes function.php file:

```
$(function() {
  var message = "Don't forget us";
  var original;

  $(window).focus(function() {
    if (original) {
      document.title = original;
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    var title = $('title').text();
    if (title != message) {
      original = title;
    }
    document.title = message;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following goes into `functions.php`

```php
add_action('wp_head', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var message = "Don't forget us"
            var original

            jQuery(window).on("focus", function () {
                if (original) {
                    document.title = original
                }
            }).on("blur", function () {
                var title = jQuery("title").text()
                if (title != message) {
                    original = title
                }
                document.title = message
            })
        })()
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put that script into a tag `<script></script>` in the footer.php file wich should be located in your theme (don't forget to actually duplicate this file inside your child theme)

EDIT: Also make sur to have JQuery in your frontend